# Как задать cron через определенный интервал со смещением по времени?

Tags: centos, администрирование, cron

Есть два задания которые запускаются раз в 5 минут, но чтобы не создавать большую нагрузку на сайт хочу сазать смещение например на 1 минуту.

Таким образом второе задание должно запускаться с опозданием в 1 минуту

```
# первое задание

/5 * * * * wget -O - https://мойсайт.рф/задание1 > /dev/null

# второе задание

/5 * * * * wget -O - https://мойсайт.рф/задание2 > /dev/null
```

Comment: Прописать 5 минут и 6 минут к другому. Так что нельзя ? :) в втором задание просто поставить 6 минут

Comment: тогда у второго интервал будет раз в 6 минут, а скорость выполнения заданий должна быть одинаковой, но если у второго поставить 6 минут то время выполнения второго задания увеличится на 20%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

замечание: `/5` — это некорректный способ указать шаг **для диапазона**. должен быть указан **и** диапазон, для которого задаёте шаг. например: `2-10/5` или `*/5` (как последний вариант, вероятно, и воспринимает *crond* ваш некорректный синтаксис).

из замечания вытекает и ответ на ваш вопрос: укажите интервал со смещением. чтобы он начинался не с нуля, а с другого количества минут/часов/дней.

это ваш текущий вариант (строки идентичны):

```
*/5 * * * * команда     # выполняется каждую 0-5-10-...-ю минуту
0-59/5 * * * * команда  # выполняется каждую 0-5-10-...-ю минуту
```

а вот со смещением в одну минуту:

```
1-59/5 * * * * команда  # выполняется каждую 1-6-11-...-ю мунуту
```